# Python - Cannot Create A Variable That Also Creates A New Line

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I Seem To Cannot Create A Variable That Also Creates A New Line

```
def S3ListAllObjects(event, context):

import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('amazons3bucket')
returnoutput = ""

for obj in bucket.objects.all():
   returnoutput += obj.key

return returnoutput
```

For whatever reason I cannot seem to make the returnme variable output a newline. I have tried many different variations of the code but have had no luck. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `"\n"`?

Comment: I have tried 

returnoutput += obj.key + "\n"

Comment: it should work then

Comment: Is obj.key a string?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want key?  Perhaps you want name?

```
>>> import boto3
>>> s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
>>> for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
        print(bucket.name)
```